# List non-suspended cronjobs using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How to select `SUSPEND=False` cronjob?

`--selector` can't be used as `suspend` is not added in the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a JSONPath expression and passing it via the `--output=jsonpath=` option to `kubectl` I was able to select only cronjobs which are unsuspended and print their names as follows:

```
kubectl get cronjob --output=jsonpath='{range .items[?(.spec.suspend==false)]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'
```

In order yo invert the selection you can simply filter on `spec.suspend==true` instead of `false`, i.e.:

```
kubectl get cronjob --output=jsonpath='{range .items[?(.spec.suspend==true)]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'
```

For explicitness you can additionally pass the `--no-headers` like so, even though the former command already does not print any headers:

```
kubectl get cronjob --no-headers --output=jsonpath='{range .items[?(.spec.suspend==false)]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Last but not least you can combine the commands above with Kubernetes selector expressions; for example:

```
kubectl get cronjob --selector=sometagkey==sometagvalue --no-headers --output=jsonpath='{range .items[?(.spec.suspend==false)]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't select spec.suspend on a kubectl filter.

You could make your own jq filter

(this is just an example and could be a lot cleaner)

```
k get cronjob --output=json | 
  jq -c 'select( .items[].spec.suspend == false)' | 
  jq  '.items[] | .metadata.name + " " + .spec.schedule + " "
  + (.spec.suspend|tostring) + " " + .spec.active'
```

Or if you don't mind a little golang

```golang
// Look at https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go 
// for the other parameters (like using current kubectl context).
func getCronsBySuspend(clientset *kubernetes.Clientset, namespace string) {
    cjs, err := clientset.BatchV1().CronJobs(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    var c []string
    for _, cron := range cjs.Items {
        if *cron.Spec.Suspend == false {
            c = append(c, cron.Name)
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v", c)
}
```